Use numpy meshgrid for only 2 out of 3 variables
I have the following variables:
centers = np.array([(2.78568, 0.0000), (4.32842, -0.775169), (7.43238, -1.000000)])
ts = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

and I want a meshgrid where each of the tuples in centers are always paired together, but they are meshed with ts. i.e., I want the following output:



sigma
tau
t




2.78568
0.000000
0.1


4.32842
-0.775169
0.1


7.43238
-1.000000
0.1


2.78568
0.000000
0.2


4.32842
-0.775169
0.2


7.43238
-1.000000
0.2


2.78568
0.000000
0.3


4.32842
-0.775169
0.3


7.43238
-1.000000
0.3



I tried this but there has to be a better way to do it?
sigmas, taus = centers[:,0], centers[:,1]
_inputs = np.array(np.meshgrid(taus, ts)).reshape(2,9).T
inputs = np.append(np.zeros((9,1)), _inputs, 1)
for input in inputs:
    center = centers[np.where(centers[:,1]==input[1])]
    input[0:2] = center

I've tried a few combinations of arguments to meshgrid but haven't achieved what I want. Can someone help?

use product from itertools np.array([np.r_[i,j] for i,j in np.emath.nx.itertools.product(ts, centers)])[:,[1,2,0]]

Thanks! I learned a lot of new functions from this comment.

There are various ways.
One would be to use repeat/tile to expand the two arrays, and then join them.
Another is to start with a zeros array of the right size (3d is easiest), assign values along the right mix of dimensions, taking advantage of broadcasting.
In [22]: res = np.zeros((centers.shape[0], ts.shape[0], centers.shape[1]+1))    

In [23]: res[:,:,:-1]=centers[None,:,:]  # (1,3,2)
In [24]: res[:,:,-1] = ts[:,None]        # (3,1)

In [25]: res
Out[25]: 
array([[[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.1     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.1     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.1     ]],

       [[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.2     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.2     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.2     ]],

       [[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.3     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.3     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.3     ]]])

Then reshape to get the 2d you want:
In [26]: res.reshape(-1,3)
Out[26]: 
array([[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.1     ],
       [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.1     ],
       [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.1     ],
       [ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.2     ],
       [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.2     ],
       [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.2     ],
       [ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.3     ],
       [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.3     ],
       [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.3     ]])

repeat
In [29]: np.concatenate((centers[None,:,:].repeat(3,0), ts[:,None,None].repeat(3,1)),axis=-1)
Out[29]: 
array([[[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.1     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.1     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.1     ]],

       [[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.2     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.2     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.2     ]],

       [[ 2.78568 ,  0.      ,  0.3     ],
        [ 4.32842 , -0.775169,  0.3     ],
        [ 7.43238 , -1.      ,  0.3     ]]])


Quite minor: use np.empty() instead of np.zeros(), and np.newaxis instead of None.

Yet another way is indices():
ii, jj = np.indices(centers.shape[:1]*2)
result = np.hstack((
    centers[jj, :].reshape((-1, centers.shape[1])),
    ts[ii].reshape((-1, 1)),
))

If I had to pick a favourite, it would be the broadcasting method in the other answer.

One way to do it is to mesh "ts" with both the "sigmas" and "taus", flatten them, and finally concatenate them in the column dimension.
import numpy as np

centers = np.array([(2.78568, 0.0000), (4.32842, -0.775169), (7.43238, -1.000000)])
ts = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

sigmas, taus = centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1]


sig_mesh, ts_mesh = np.meshgrid(sigmas, ts)
tau_mesh, ts_mesh = np.meshgrid(taus, ts)

sig, tau, t = sig_mesh.flatten(), tau_mesh.flatten(), ts_mesh.flatten()


y = np.concatenate((sig.reshape(-1, 1), tau.reshape(-1, 1), t.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1)

print(y)

Hope this helps. :)
